# Rotate Array in Swift

Tags: swift, algorithm

While exploring algorithms in Swift, couldn't find algorithm for array rotation in swift without using funcs `shiftLeft` / `shiftRight`.

C has this graceful algo with time complexity of O(N):

```
/* Function to left rotate arr[] of size n by d */
void leftRotate(int arr[], int d, int n)
{
    rvereseArray(arr, 0, d-1);
    rvereseArray(arr, d, n-1);
    rvereseArray(arr, 0, n-1);
}

/*Function to reverse arr[] from index start to end*/
void rvereseArray(int arr[], int start, int end)
{
    int temp;
    while (start < end)
    {
        temp = arr[start];
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
```

I'm struggling with converting this into swift:

```
func rotate(array:[Int], positions:Int, arSize:Int) {

    var a = array
    var p = positions
    var s = arSize

    reverseArray(array: a, start: 0, end: p-1)
    reverseArray(array: a, start: p, end: s-1)
    reverseArray(array: a, start: 0, end: s-1)
}

func reverseArray(array: [Int], start:Int, end:Int) {

    var a = array
    var s = start
    var e = end
    var temp = 0
    while s < e {
        temp = a[s]
        a[s] = a[e]
        a[e] = temp
        s += 1
        e -= 1
    }
}
```

As I understand, for swift,  we need to specify return types. 
How they should be configured without increasing space(memory) complexity? (aka, without creating new temporary arrays)

---

This question is different from others, because its about how `returns` work in swift compare to C.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a mutating method?

Comment: just a method for an array rotation.

Comment: now I see what actually `mutating` means.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit update:

**Swift 5 or later**

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    func rotatingLeft(positions: Int) -> SubSequence {
        let index = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: positions, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
        return self[index...] + self[..<index]
    }
    mutating func rotateLeft(positions: Int) {
        let index = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: positions, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
        let slice = self[..<index]
        removeSubrange(..<index)
        insert(contentsOf: slice, at: endIndex)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    func rotatingRight(positions: Int) -> SubSequence {
        let index = self.index(endIndex, offsetBy: -positions, limitedBy: startIndex) ?? startIndex
        return self[index...] + self[..<index]
    }
    mutating func rotateRight(positions: Int) {
        let index = self.index(endIndex, offsetBy: -positions, limitedBy: startIndex) ?? startIndex
        let slice = self[index...]
        removeSubrange(index...)
        insert(contentsOf: slice, at: startIndex)
    }
}
```

---

```
var test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
test.rotateLeft(positions: 3)   // [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3]

var test2 = "1234567890"
test2.rotateRight(positions: 3)   // "8901234567"
```

Comment: what is (size ?? count) ? is that 'either/or' operator?

Comment: It is nil coalescing operator it will pass the array count in case you don't pass the size. Also you should make sure you don't pass a size bigger that the array count

Comment: What if the parameter "positions" exceeds the size of array?

Comment: Nice solution, that takes O(1) space, right? If `removeSubrange()` could accept `Int` parameter that would be more better. Because just get an index from `index(endIndex, offsetBy: -positions, limitedBy: startIndex)` looks weird to me.

Comment: @ChuckZHB this is generic to allow you to use with any kind of collection (like strings as well). You can also add another method and constrain the index to Int. `extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Index == Int {` `mutating func rotateLeft(positions: Int) {` `let index = Swift.min(positions, endIndex)` `let slice = self[..<index]` `removeSubrange(..<index)` `insert(contentsOf: slice, at: endIndex)` `}` `}`

Comment: if you would like to allow to rotate a value greater the the number of elements you can use `let index = positions % endIndex`

Comment: That is better, thanks. I just want to take a shorter format when dealing with some array rotating algorithm problem in Swift. When I use while loop, it would take O(n) space since I create another array. This `self.rotateLeft(self.count - k)` simply rotate k times from an array, which is cool.

Comment: @ChuckZHB you can also create a non mutating method. Check my last edit

Comment: Yes! Adding `mutating` before the method name let us able to change the caller array `self`.

Answer (score 12):

We can use Slice

```
func rotLeft(a: [Int], d: Int) -> [Int] {
    let slice1 = a[..<d]
    let slice2 = a[d...]
    return Array(slice2) + Array(slice1)
}

print(rotLeft(a:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], d: 4))

//prints [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: What if the value of d exceeds the count?
This solution does not handle every scenario.

Comment: lets array is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and d = 3 what's the your result. I am expecting [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 7):

Why create a reverse function when we already have it in the Swift standard library?
My solution (derived from Leo Dabus'):

```
extension Array {
    mutating func rotate(positions: Int, size: Int? = nil) {
        let size = size ?? count
        guard positions < count && size <= count else { return }

        self[0..<positions].reverse()
        self[positions..<size].reverse()
        self[0..<size].reverse()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Approach 1:

```
func rotate(_ nums: inout [Int], _ k: Int) {
    nums.enumerated().forEach { nums[ (k + $0)  % nums.count] = $1 }
}
```

Approach 2:

```
func rotLeft(a: [Int], d: Int) -> [Int] {
    var a = a
    
    reverse(&a, 0, d)
    reverse(&a, d, a.count)
    reverse(&a, 0, a.count)
    return a
}

func reverse(_ a: inout [Int], _ s: Int, _ r: Int) {
    var r = r, s = s
    
    while s < r {
        a.swapAt(s, r - 1)
        s += 1
        r -= 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be complete, the rotation function should support negative (right) rotations and rotating more than the array's size

```
extension Array 
{
    mutating func rotateLeft(by rotations:Int) 
    { 
       // rotation irrelevant when less than 2 elements
       if count < 2 { return }  

       // effective left rotation for negative and > count
       let rotations = (rotations%count + count) % count 

       // no use rotating by zero
       if rotations == 0 { return } 

       // rotate
       (1..<count).reduce(0)
       { let i = ($0.0+rotations)%count; swap(&self[$0.0],&self[i]); return i }
    }

    mutating func reverse()
    {
       (0..<count/2).forEach{ swap(&self[$0],&self[count-$0-1]) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

// a is the array to be left rotated
// d is the number of unit for left rotation

```
func rotLeft(a: [Int], d: Int) -> [Int] {
    var a = a
    for index in 0...(d - 1) {
       a.append(a[0])
       a.remove(at: 0)
     }
    return a
 }
```

// calling Function

```
rotLeft(a: [1,2,3,4,5], d: 4)
```

// OutPut
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: this is my first answer to solve the problem statement. but if you try submit the code it hits timeout on hackerrank

Answer (score 1):

This solution rotates the element of time complexity O(n)

```
func rotLeft(a: [Int], d: Int) -> [Int] {
   var arr = a
   var size = arr.count - 1
   for i in 0...size  {
     let newloc = (i + (arr.count - d)) % arr.count
     arr[newloc] = a[i]
   }
   return arr
}
```

you shouldn't use `.append(x)`  as in the worst case it can be 
O(n) and  you shouldn't use `.remove(at: x)` as its O(n) when you can avoid using those methods As when using them you basically get n + n + n   which isn't that great

Comment: newloc can be negative using this expression and you will get an exception trying to access this index.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody lands here after watching the [Embracing Algorithms](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/223/?time=2142) WWDC18 session by [David Abrahams](https://twitter.com/DaveAbrahams), here is one of the implementations of rotate from the [swift/test/Prototypes/Algorithms.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/Prototypes/Algorithms.swift) file.

```
extension MutableCollection where Self: BidirectionalCollection {
    /// Rotates the elements of the collection so that the element
    /// at `middle` ends up first.
    ///
    /// - Returns: The new index of the element that was first
    ///   pre-rotation.
    /// **- Complexity: O(*n*)**
    @discardableResult
    public mutating func rotate(shiftingToStart middle: Index) -> Index {
        self[..<middle].reverse()
        self[middle...].reverse()
        let (p, q) = _reverseUntil(middle)
        self[p..<q].reverse()
        return middle == p ? q : p
        }
    }
```

This algorithms depends on *reverseUntil(*:) defined in the same file

```
extension MutableCollection where Self: BidirectionalCollection {

/// Reverses the elements of the collection, moving from each end until
/// `limit` is reached from either direction. The returned indices are the
/// start and end of the range of unreversed elements.
///
///     Input:
///     [a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p]
///             ^
///           limit
///     Output:
///     [p o n m e f g h i j k l d c b a]
///             ^               ^
///             f               l
///
/// - Postcondition: For returned indices `(f, l)`:
///   `f == limit || l == limit`
@inline(__always)
@discardableResult
internal mutating func _reverseUntil(_ limit: Index) -> (Index, Index) {
    var f = startIndex
    var l = endIndex
    while f != limit && l != limit {
        formIndex(before: &l)
        swapAt(f, l)
        formIndex(after: &f)
    }
    return (f, l)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the scenario such as-

The number of rotation can be equal/more than the size of array you need to rotate.

To handle this scenario use modulo operator to find the actual number of rotation as you will find out rotating an array by a number equal to its size result in same array.

```
    func rotateLeft(array:[Int],numberOfRotation:Int) -> [Int]
    {
     let offset = numberOfRotation % array.count
     let tempResult = array[offset...] + array[..<offset]
     return Array(tempResult)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using Array's dropFirst() and dropLast() functions.

```
func rotateLeft(arrToRotate: inout [Int], positions: Int){
  if arrToRotate.count == 0 || positions == 0 || positions > arrToRotate.count{
      print("invalid")
      return
  }
  arrToRotate = arrToRotate.dropFirst(positions) + arrToRotate.dropLast(arrToRotate.count-positions)
}

var numbers : [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
rotateLeft(arrToRotate: &numbers, positions:2)
print(numbers)  //prints [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a way to rotate left or right. Just call rotate on your array as shown. This does not mutate the array, if you wish to mutate the array, set the array equal to the rotation.

```
extension Array {
    func rotate(moveRight: Bool, numOfRotations: Int) -> Array<Element>{
        var arr = self
        var i = 0
        while i < numOfRotations {
            if moveRight {
                arr.insert(arr.remove(at: arr.count - 1), at: 0)
            } else {
                arr.append(arr.remove(at: 0))
            }
            i += 1
        }
        return arr
    }
}

var arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

print(arr.rotate(moveRight: true, numOfRotations: 2))
// ["d", "e", "a", "b", "c"]
print(arr)
// ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
arr = arr.rotate(moveRight: true, numOfRotations: 2)
print(arr)
// ["d", "e", "a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

O(n) + O(m) complexity for rotateLeft and taking care of edge cases where rotation count is bigger than array size:

```swift
func rotLeft(a: [Int], d: Int) -> [Int] {
    var temp = a
    let rot = d % a.count
    let movable = temp[..<rot]
    temp.removeFirst(rot)
    temp.append(contentsOf: movable)
    return temp
}
```